# How to do "bulk insert" with Hanami when I use migration

Tags: ruby, database-migration, hanami

Recently I have tried using Hanami, Ruby framework. I would like to execute migration with "bulk insert".

I checked following issue discussion.

- [Proposal: multi_create method for bulk records #406](https://github.com/hanami/model/issues/406)

But, I don't understand how to call `ROM` object from Hanami. Would you please explain how to do that and any web site to refer ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I have realized meaning of code.

At first, I wrote `bulk_insert` as instance method.

- `somes` represents SQL table's name, I could use this with symbol

**Repository sample**

```
class SomeRepository < Hanami::Repository
  def bulk_insert(data)
    command(:create, somes, use: [:timestamps], result: :many).call(data)
  end
end
```

**Bulk insert sample**

```
# we can pass array of hash
SomeRepository.new.bulk_insert(some_array)
SomeRepository.new.bulk_insert([{name: "sample1"}, {name: "sample2"}, {name: "sample3"}])
```